# How can I use an array of indexes to nagivate an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I'm making a checklist app and need to navigate through my data to edit the `complete:false`

My data is structured with children being an optional key, and objects with children won't have the completed key.

There are two ways I could solve this

1. use each part of the `path` and navigate the array  using `items[path[0]]` and so on
2. Or use `path` as (or replace it with) a unique `id` and search for that id

both of which I do not know how to do

```
const TESTDATA = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    path: [0],
    open: true,
    children: [
      { name: 'bar', completed: false, path: [0, 0] },
      { name: 'data', completed: false, path: [0, 1] },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'foo',
    path: [1],
    open: true,
    children: [
      { name: 'bar', completed: false, path: [1, 0] },
      {
        name: 'data',
        completed: false,
        path: [1, 1],
        children: [{ name: 'baz', completed: false, path: [1, 1, 0] }],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Is there a way to recursively (or not) search for a specific path/id in all the children keys and return the item so it could be modified?

Comment: I see two objects with `path: [0, 1]`. Is `path` supposed to be unique?

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I'll clear up the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. Follow `path`

This is the more direct way, as we can literally go and find the wanted element. As such, this is likely more performant.

Here is one way to do it:

1. Navigate through all necessary `.children`.
2. Take the element specified by the last index in `path`.

**1. Navigate `.children`:**

```js
function findChild(path, data) {
  let array = data;
  for (let i = 0; i < path.length - 1; ++i) {
    const pathIndex = path[i];
    array = array[pathIndex].children;
  }
  // ...
}
```

**2. Take element by last index:**

```js
function findChild(path, data) {
  let array = data;
  for (let i = 0; i < path.length - 1; ++i) {
    const pathIndex = path[i];
    array = array[pathIndex].children;
  }
  return array[path[path.length - 1]];
}
```

We actually haven't yet taken edge-cases into account, namely:

1. What if `data` (or any array here) is an empty array?
2. What if elements along the given path don't have `.children`?

Here's a fix to that:

```js
function findChild(path, data) {
  let array = data;
  for (let i = 0; i < path.length - 1 && array; ++i) {
    const pathIndex = path[i];
    array = array[pathIndex]?.children;
  }
  return array?.[path[path.length - 1]];
}
```

```js
function findChild(path, data) {
  let array = data;
  for (let i = 0; i < path.length - 1 && array; ++i) {
    const pathIndex = path[i];
    array = array[pathIndex]?.children;
  }
  return array?.[path[path.length - 1]];
}

const data = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    path: [0],
    open: true,
    children: [
      { name: 'bar', completed: false, path: [0, 0] },
      { name: 'data', completed: false, path: [0, 1] },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'foo',
    path: [1],
    open: true,
    children: [
      { name: 'bar', completed: false, path: [1, 0] },
      {
        name: 'data',
        completed: false,
        path: [1, 1],
        children: [{ name: 'baz', completed: false, path: [1, 1, 0] }],
      },
    ],
  },
];

console.time();
const result = findChild([1, 0], data);
console.timeEnd();
console.log("Imperative:", result);
```

## 2. Find by `path` (as ID)

Ideally we have all elements in a single, flat array, because then we can simply do a `Array.find()` search.

Because we initially get the elements in a tree-like structure, we have to flatten them manually. Here is one way to do that:

```js
const _flatten = (el) => ([el, ...(el.children ?? []).flatMap(_flatten)]);
const flatten = (array) => array.flatMap(_flatten);
```

Now that we have a flat array of all the elements, we can use `Array.find()`:

```js
function findChild(path, treeElements) {
  const isEqual = (a1, a2) => {
    if (a1.length !== a2.length) return false;
    return a1.every((v, i) => v === a2[i]);
  };

  const _flatten = (el) => ([el, ...(el.children ?? []).flatMap(_flatten)]);
  const flatten = (array) => array.flatMap(_flatten);

  return flatten(treeElements).find(el => isEqual(el.path, path));
}
```

```js
function findChild(path, treeElements) {
  const isEqual = (a1, a2) => {
    if (a1.length !== a2.length) return false;
    return a1.every((v, i) => v === a2[i]);
  };

  const _flatten = (el) => ([el, ...(el.children ?? []).flatMap(_flatten)]);
  const flatten = (array) => array.flatMap(_flatten);

  return flatten(treeElements).find(el => isEqual(el.path, path));
}

const data = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    path: [0],
    open: true,
    children: [
      { name: 'bar', completed: false, path: [0, 0] },
      { name: 'data', completed: false, path: [0, 1] },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'foo',
    path: [1],
    open: true,
    children: [
      { name: 'bar', completed: false, path: [1, 0] },
      {
        name: 'data',
        completed: false,
        path: [1, 1],
        children: [{ name: 'baz', completed: false, path: [1, 1, 0] }],
      },
    ],
  },
];

console.time();
const result = findChild([1, 0], data);
console.timeEnd();
console.log("Functional:", result);
```

## Comparison between 1. and 2.

As per [JSBen.ch](https://jsben.ch/ZVdFc), the first option compared to the second option is about 3-4 times faster, as expected.

(The implementation for the `isEqual()` function is the quickest as per [this benchmark](https://jsben.ch/pkiHM).)

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this can get you started:

```
function gather(name, obj){
 if(name==obj.name) return obj;
 if(obj.children) return obj.children.map(x=>gather(name, x)).flat().filter(Boolean)
}

TESTDATA.map(x=>gather("baz", x)).flat()[0]
```